# Does my laptop have BIOS or EFI?

Tags: grub2, bios, uefi, sony

I have a Sony VAIO S Series Laptop ( Model: VPCSE190X )

http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&categoryId=8198552921644768015#/s15specificationTabContent

Is there a command or method I could use to find out if my laptop has BIOS or EFI?

Comment: I've found that many devices these days have a form of UEFI that is BIOS-compatible, and they don't brag about it.  But unfortunately I have no idea about that particular laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Manual says nothing about EFI.  but has multiple refs to the bios setup screen.

I'm thinking classic bios on this one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, do you have the same laptop?

Comment: @Jason No.  I dont, but I had a manual in the server doc repo, so someone I know does.  =p